# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime format exception

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, datetime-format

I am trying to do a simple parsing using following statements:

```
//In actual code the date time value comes from db
var dateTime = new DateTime(2018, 04, 26);

var dtExtact = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTime.ToString(), "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff",null);
```

Now when I try doing this getting error,

> System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'

I did have a look at the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) sample, but it does not provide any pointers on whats wrong with my date time.

Comment: Because `dateTime.ToString()` probably doesn't produce a string in the format "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff".

Comment: MMM seems like too many digits to parse.

Comment: @RobertSim `MMM` represents ("Jan", "Feb", etc) or the equivalents based on the CultureInfo.

Comment: I can't help but wonder why you're doing this. Do these values really come out of your database as strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you would like to parse a date-time string in a specific format, make sure that your formatted date/time string matches the format of your parser.

In your example "round-tripping" a date/time is easy to achieve by reusing the same format string for formatting the date and for parsing:

```
var dateTime = new DateTime(2018, 04, 26);
const string dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff";
var dtExact = DateTime.ParseExact(
    dateTime.ToString(dateFormat)
,   dateFormat
,   null
);
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", dateTime, dtExact);
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/8WBqvd)

Comment: Obviously such round-tripping only works when both parts run on the same (or similarly configured) machine. If you need to roundtrip value that involves sending data out of process - use ["O" as format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#Roundtrip).

Answer (score 1):

Both ToString() and Parse() are designed to automagically extract the Region setting from Windows. It is rarely a good idea to override this behavior. And apparently your pattern is not a valid one. For all we know, ':' is not actually the proper cultural seperator for Time elements

Overall this seems rather suspect - you turn a DateTime to string, only to parse it again right there. I can only guess it is for testing. But testing for what is the question.

I have 3 general rules when dealing with DateTimes:

- Always store, retrieve and transmit the UTC value. You do not want ot add timezones to your issues. [That way lies madness](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY). There are rare exceptions, but then you are pretty much on your own to deal with that mess
- Avoid storing, retreival or transmission as Text. keep it in proper DataTypes as long as possible
- If you can follow the 2nd rule (using XML or some other serialsiation), at least pick a fixed Culture Format, Format String and string encoding at all endpoints. You do not want to add those issues to your worries

Following those rules, I rarely had any issues.